# What is the standard or best practice for bitcoin wallet address labeling, if any?

Tags: wallet, address, privacy, coin-control

Transferring wallet address labels from different wallets is non-trivial today, as there is no standard for this metadata it seems.

- Could address labelling be included in wallet config files at export?
- Could wallet descriptors help in the future?
- Is there any best practices today or wallet recommended for this?

The goal is to keep a clean and updated state of wallet addresses labeling for easy coin control and good privacy, while not being locked in with a wallet that does not let a user export their labels. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Use a money for transacting and a spreadsheet for accounting.

Comment: There was talk of a BIP for a Wallet Labels Export Format on the Bitcoin Dev mailing list in August last year: https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/bitcoin-dev/2022-August/020887.html which might be of interest in this context.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. This thread is great. Digging deeper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BIP referenced by Murch in the comments has been opened as [BIP-329](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0329.mediawiki)

Comment: Thank you Turbolay ;)